# The result obtained from pandas series operation cannot get assigned to a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I am using IMDB reviews dataset containing two columns - sentiment and review. I am trying to convert the review column to a list so as to perform loop operations but when I assign my series(review column) to a variable and print the variable, the output shows nothing. When I separately print `df['review'].values.tolist()` without assigning to any variable, it correctly outputs a list.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code as text, not picture

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem but you can probably solve it simply by improving your code.

1. Make a function that parse one sentence
2. Apply this function to all elements in the column `review`

Basically, your code should look like this:

```py
def parse_sentence(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    sentence = re.sub(pattern, '', sentence)
    ...
    return sentence

clean_reviews = df["review"].map(parse_sentence)
print(clean_review)
```